# Model fit for Lavaan CFA. What is the problem with this code?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I have implemented a confirmatory factor analysis using the lavaan package in R. The code I wrote produces the following error:

### **lavaan 0.6-7 did NOT end normally after 2044 iterations**

Could someone kindly give me some help, please?

```
##PACKAGES
library(lavaan)
library(semTools)
library(semPlot)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
##DATASET
dataset_ita <- read_excel("dataset_ita.xlsx", col_types = "numeric")
dataset_eng <- read_excel("dataset_eng.xlsx", col_types = "numeric")
dataset <- rbind(dataset_ita, dataset_eng)
##CONFIRMATORY FACTOR ANALYSIS
model <- '
WinePurchaseBehaviour    =~ X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11
WineConsumptionBehaviour =~ X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+X20+X21+X22+X23+X24+X25
WineClubInterest         =~ X26+X27+X28+X29+X30+X31+X64+X65+X66+X67
WineInvolvement          =~ WinePurchaseBehaviour+WineConsumptionBehaviour+WineClubInterest
GeneralInvolvement       =~ X32+X33+X34+X35+X36+X37+X38+X39+X40
FeatureInvolvement       =~ X44+X46+X47+X48+X49
RitualInvolvement        =~ X41+X42+X43+X45+X50
AppExperience            =~ X51+X52+X53+X54+X55+X56+X57+X58
SensoryExperience        =~ X59+X60+X61+X62+X63
ProductInvolvement       =~ GeneralInvolvement+FeatureInvolvement+AppExperience+SensoryExperience
Purchase                =~ X68+X69+X70+X71+X72+X73
Purchase                =~ WineInvolvement+ProductInvolvement'

analysis <- cfa(model, data = dataset, se = "robust.sem")
summary(analysis, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

[The datasets can be found here](https://github.com/alecorsi93/CFA---lavvan-.git)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It would be easier for us to help you if we had code and data to reproduce the problem. There is a helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible R example that may be useful.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the question by adding a reproducible R example and the link for the github repository in order to download the datasets needed for the confirmatory factor analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at the data and it seems that `RitualInvolvement` factor just doesn't work - it doesn't work on its own even.  The `FeatureInolvement` factor worked better using `X47` as the coefficient set to 1, so use that first in the list.  The model below, without estimating the `RitualInvolvement` factor estimates and converges for me.

```
model <- '
WinePurchaseBehaviour    =~ X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11
WineConsumptionBehaviour =~ X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+X20+X21+X22+X23+X24+X25
WineClubInterest         =~ X26+X27+X28+X29+X30+X31+X64+X65+X66+X67
WineInvolvement          =~ WinePurchaseBehaviour+WineConsumptionBehaviour+WineClubInterest
GeneralInvolvement       =~ X32+X33+X34+X35+X36+X37+X38+X39+X40
FeatureInvolvement       =~ X47+X46+X44+X48+X49
# RitualInvolvement        =~ X41+X42+X43+X45+X50
AppExperience            =~ X51+X52+X53+X54+X55+X56+X57+X58
SensoryExperience        =~ X59+X60+X61+X62+X63
ProductInvolvement       =~ GeneralInvolvement+FeatureInvolvement+AppExperience+SensoryExperience
Purchase                =~ X68+X69+X70+X71+X72+X73
Purchase                =~ WineInvolvement+ProductInvolvement'
analysis <- cfa(model, data = dataset, se = "robust.sem")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meantime I've discovered that, by removing the variable X43 from RitualInvolvement, the model converges...... that's sounds very strange!! I keep working on it!!